# Should I use the past perfect "have thought", or the present "think" with "would"?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

I don't know if you watch *Champions League*, which is a European soccer league. However, in the beginning of this season, no one expected that Juve, an Italian team, could reach the semi final, but Juve did. so I wrote this sentence

> No one would have thought that Juve could play the semi final for this year.

is it correct? or it should be

> No one would think that Juve could play the semi final for this year?

Comment: Your first sentence is correct: **No one would have thought that Juve could play semi final for this year.** or you can also simply say **No one ever thought that Juve could play semi final for this year.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No-one had any doubts that they could 'play' it - the doubt was that they would still be in the competition at that stage; so 'play' is not interchangeable with 'reach'.
Longer form would be maybe 'get as far as'.
Meaning 2 at [OALD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reach) which has some other synonyms too. *Not all of these would work for this sentence; those in italics are definitely out*:

> arrive at, get to, get as far as, *come to*, make it
> to, *gain*,   end up at, *land up at, set foot on*
>
> informal: make, *hit*

Also, there's no need for 'for this year'. Just 'this year'.

Something I can't put my finger on also wants me to substitute 'could' for 'would'.

There are also some 'football-specific' ways that commentators/pundits refer to things…
Semi-finals is almost always plural if you are referring generally to both, at a distance - there are two of them, of course, yet only one final.
If you were referring to one specific match, 'the semi-final between A & B' then it would be singular.

They also almost always refer to the 'year' as the 'season'.

So, one option, very colloquial & 'football-style' would be...

> No-one would have thought that Juve would make the semi-finals this season.

Comment: is it a type when u wrote `have have`? it should be one `have` right?